# Changing calendar's color in Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar

I would like to create and manage all my calendars' settings on the **Settings** page on the left side by the following URL: https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r/settings

[image]

However I could not find the option to specify the calendar color. Do we get a chance to specify it there on that settings page, instead of going to the homepage https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r and specify the color by pressing the three dots next to calendar?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, sorry. It would appear that *color* is the one thing you can't change about the calendar from the settings page. For the moment, the only place to change it is on the main page by using the options menu.

Comment: Thank you for response. That's pity, but would be nice if they implement this change in the next releases.

Comment: Use the "Send Feedback" tool in the gear menu to tell Google so.